# Tuning van side-door

Tags: door, van

My Iveco 35c18 (2010) van has this kind of side door

[image]

It closes by inserting these pins

[image]

into these 'holes'

[image]

However, the door is slightly below its proper position

[image]

Here's the upper door axis

[image]
[image]

And the lower door axis

[image]
[image]

How can I tune the door so that (1) it goes a little bit higher (and the pins align with the holes) and (2) so that the door shuts a little bit closer to the van (it is leaving a 0.5cm gap, makes it rain inside the van)?

Comment: What make/model/year is your van?

Comment: I bet the pin misalignment and the rain gap are related, i.e. fix the pin alignment and the top will seal better.  From your pics (I don't have any drawings or manuals to back this up), it looks like all of the height adjustment is done through the bottom bracket.  The top bracket looks like it auto-adjust to whatever height the bottom bracket enforces.  Is it *evenly* misaligned?  Like, when closed, is the top gap uniform, is the gap bigger at the front or rear end?

Comment: What has happened during the life of the van to cause the door to lose alignment? - Since you need to loosen the bolts holding the lower bracket to make any adjustments, you might as well take the opportunity to remove the lower bracket entirely and check the rollers for damage or excess wear.

Comment: The lower bracket is new. I feel that the upper bracket is the one holding the door, the lower one is just a slider. There is also another bracket, which I didn't mention, on the back of the door, at medium height. I think that is also supporting the door height. I've also edited the van model in the post.

Comment: Literally the only thing I see in your pictures (not a manual) that could adjust the height are the 2 (or more) bolts attaching the bottom bracket to the door.  The holes in that plate are elongated to allow a little adjustment; the top plate does not have the fancy holes.  The top bracket looks like it articulates vertically right below the weather-seal.  Both the top and bottom bracket can be adjusted to be closer or farther from the van body.  On the top bracket, it looks like the close/far adjustment is done by the bolt on the bottom right next to the black plastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ZachMierzejwski says in his comment, it looks like the adjustment is done in the bottom bracket - the three bolts holding the door to the bracket are slotted to allow for height adjustment (it looks like they are sitting on their lowest positions), and the two bolts holding the two parts of the bracket together are also slotted, which would allow some in/out adjustment.

There may also be adjustment possible in the centre mount - the one at the back of the door, which you've not pictured.

Position a trolley jack or bottle jack (or two) under the door, with a couple of blocks of wood to protect it. Take the weight of the door on the jacks, then slacken the bolts. Lift it by the appropriate amount, then tighten them. Check the fit, then repeat as necessary. Repeat for the sideways adjustment...